# Applying nftables rules to macvtap interfaces

Tags: iptables, nftables

I'm trying to expose a libvirt (qemu) virtual machine to the open world on a separate address via a promiscuous device and attached macvtap, but at the same time protect the local network from snooping, e.g. by banning 192.168.0.0/16 (with an exception of special addresses, broadcast/gateway/dns). However, it looks like my rules are not applied to a child macvtap device altogether, even recommended meta tracing flag with the lowest priority in the ruleset marks only enp88s0 packets, but not macvtap0 packets. Is it possible to intercept macvtap traffic with nftables? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MACVTAP](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#macvtap_ipvtap) interface, a variation of [MACVLAN](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#macvlan) for VMs hijacks frames sent to the host interface which have the VM's NIC's Ethernet MAC address as destination. Likewise, frames sent by the VM are injected on the host's physical interface toward outside. This also usually means that the VM and the host can't communicate directly (both will send to outside without the other receiving it, unless for example a switch in VEPA mode is used, or the traffic between themselves is routed).

As the traffic for the VM is neither for the host's routing stack: `ip`/`ip6`/`inet` or `arp` *nftables* families, nor for an host bridge: `bridge` *nftables* family, it won't be seen in these families (except in `inet ingress` see below).

### [`netdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#NETDEV_ADDRESS_FAMILY), `ingress` and `egress`

Yet there's still the `netdev` family with its `ingress` and `egress` (kernel >= 5.16) hooks which can see such traffic. Actually for convenience, the `inet` family also has such `ingress` hook limited to IPv4/IPv6 (but has no equivalent `egress` hook). Here `ingress` has the same direction as the actual interface: from "outside" to the userspace process (QEMU). `egress` is from the userspace process to "outside".

No *conntrack* facility will be available at this level: no stateful filtering can be done. If there's the need to filter both directions (`egress` requiring kernel >= 5.16 and recent *nftables*), or to filter other protocols than IPv4/IPv6 (such as ARP), then only the `netdev` family can provide it.

In addition these hooks are somewhat special: they are attached to one or multiple interface(s) and the syntax to define a chain reflects this: it has to include the keyword `device` (or `devices =` ) and a device (or a list of devices).

So if the interface is named `macvtap0` (but see the Bonus paragraph for *libvirt* integration), a ruleset blocking 192.168.0.0/16 except 192.168.2.1 (and not caring about filtering by Ethernet MAC address or ARP protocol because it's just an example) would look like this (typically the start of the filter at the Ethernet layer `ether type ip` is implied by `ip saddr` and omitted):

```
table netdev filtermacvtap {
    chain filterin {
        type filter hook ingress device "macvtap0" priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.2.1 accept
        ip saddr 192.168.0.0/16 drop

    }

    chain filterout {
        type filter hook egress device "macvtap0" priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 192.168.2.1 accept
        ip daddr 192.168.0.0/16 drop
    }
}
```

Remove the `filterout` chain if using a kernel < 5.16 (it's probably not really useful anyway).

### Bonus: *libvirt* integration

This also means this ruleset can't be created before the VM's interface has been created., because the device reference has to exist beforehand. *libvirt* offers [hooks](https://libvirt.org/hooks.html#etc-libvirt-hooks-qemu) to help with this:

> `/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu`
>
> [...]
>
> The second location, available Since 0.8.0 , occurs after libvirt has
> finished labeling all resources, but has not yet started the guest,
> called as:
>
> ```
> /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu guest_name start begin -
> ```

With the help of [`xmlstarlet`](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) (which is a command more difficult to use than `xmllint` but offers better output and has an [example in *libvirt*'s documentation](https://wiki.libvirt.org/OVS_and_PVLANS.html#hook-script)) one can retrieve the dynamically created interface name from the `start begin` *libvirt* hook and use it as parameter in an adequate *nftables* ruleset.

Ruleset file `/etc/filtermacvtap.nft`:

```
table netdev filtermacvtap        # for idempotence
delete table netdev filtermacvtap # for idempotence

table netdev filtermacvtap {
    chain filterin {
        type filter hook ingress device $intf priority filter; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.2.1 accept
        ip saddr 192.168.0.0/16 drop

    }

    chain filterout {
        type filter hook egress device $intf priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 192.168.2.1 accept
        ip daddr 192.168.0.0/16 drop
    }
}
```

After having done:

```
mkdir -p /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d
```

and restarted *libvirtd*; create and make executable the file below that will trigger only for a VM named `myvm` and work only when using a MACVTAP interface linked to `enp88s0`.

`/etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu.d/installfiltermacvtap.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

VM=myvm
LINKINTF=enp88s0

if [ "$1" = "$VM" ] && [ "$2" = start ] && [ "$3" = begin ]; then
    xmlstarlet select -t \
        -m 'domain/devices/interface[@type="direct"]' \
        -m "source[@dev='$LINKINTF']" \
        -m .. \
        -v 'target/@dev' \
    | {
        read intf
        nft -D intf="$intf" -f /etc/filtermacvtap.nft
    }
fi
```

There the name of the MACVTAP interface linked to the actual interface `enp88s0` is retrieved from *libvirt* (VM's xmldump available as input) and defined as parameter `$intf` for invoking *nftables*.

Cleanup is left as an exercise (though the chains will disappear when their referenced interface disappears, leaving an harmless empty table).

Comment: Thanks! Even wit nftabes wiki back online i highly doubt i'd found/figued it all by myself.